# Juego piedra papel tijeras JavaScript devuelve resultados no correctos

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables

No se porque me devuelve mal los resultados, saca que he perdido cuando la maquina uso tijeras y yo piedra, tambien saca empate cuando no lo es etc.. a veces acierta y otras no no entiendo que le sucede a mi codigo y/o tambien si se puede dejar mas claro.

mi codigo

```
const getUserChoice = function getUserChoice(userInput) {
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
if (
  userInput === "rock" ||
  userInput === "paper" ||
  userInput === "scissors"
) {
  return userInput;
} else {
  console.log("Error");
}
};

const getComputerChoice = function getComputerChoice() {
 let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
 switch (randomNumber) {
   case 0:
    return "rock"
     break; 

   case 1:
     return "paper"
     break; 

   case 2:
     return "scissors"
     break; 

   default:
     "Error";
     break;
  
 }
 };

 const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
 if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
  return "The game is a tie!";
 }


 if (userChoice === "rock") {
   if (computerChoice === "paper") {
     return "Has perdido!";
   } else {
     return "Has ganado!";
   }
 }


 if (userChoice === "paper") {

   if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
    return "Has perdido!";
   } else {
     return "Has ganado!";
   }
 } 

 if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
   if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
     return 'Has perdido!';
    } else {
    return 'Has ganado!';
   }
  }

  };

const playGame = () => {
  userChoice = getUserChoice("rock");
  computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  console.log(getUserChoice("rock"));
  console.log(getComputerChoice());

 console.log( determineWinner(userChoice, getComputerChoice) );
   };

  playGame();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes casi todo bien. Los `if`'s, aunque pueden ser reescritos de una manera más simple, están bien. Tu problema está en el método `playGame()`

Estás obteniendo la elección de la computadora en la línea:

> `computerChoice = getComputerChoice();`

Esta línea obtiene un valor **aleatorio** cada vez que se ejecuta. Entonces, lo primero que haces es guardar ese valor en la variable `computerChoice`.

Luego, imprimes una **segunda ejecución de ese método** en la línea:

> `console.log(getComputerChoice());`

Este valor que imprimes en la consola **puede ser diferente** al que tengas guardado en la variable `computerChoice`. Aquí está el **primer problema**. El valor puede o no ser el mismo y no puedes confiar lo que te dice el `console.log()`.

Tu segundo problema es cuando llamas

> `determineWinner(userChoice, getComputerChoice);`

El segundo argumento que estás pasando no es un valor, es una referencia a la función. Si te fijas, te faltan los paréntesis. Entonces, en la primera evaluación:

```
if (userChoice === "rock") {
 if (computerChoice === "paper") { // computerChoice es una referencia a una función. NO es string.
  return "Has perdido!";
 } else {
    return "Has ganado!"; // Por eso dice que has ganado.
    }
}
```

### Solución

Tienes dos opciones:

1. En lugar de pasar la referencia a la función, o pasar la llamada a la función, puedes pasar el resultado que anteriormente guardaste en la variable:

`determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice)`

2. Pasa el llamado a la función como segundo argumento:

`determineWinner(userChoice, getComputerChoice())`;

Si vas con la opción 2, recuerda que el resultado de la función es aleatorio, entonces, no confíes en el `console.log` que tienes arriba.

Comment: Efectivamente no podia confiar en el console.log porque le llamo 2 veces vale vale. Para probar la solucion 1 hice esto                                                `console.log( determineWinner(userChoice, 'scissors') );`   /// Hay alguna forma de que yo vea el valor de la ultima llamada de computechoice para ver sacar bien los datos. No se si me explico

Comment: Vale si dandole en el `console.log(computerChoice)` como dijiste en vez `console.log(getComputerChoice)`  asi evito llamarla dos veces. Muchisimas gracias por resolverme la duda estaba bloqueado ^^